# How to implement SecurityPermission on .NET sdk 5?

Tags: c#, .net-core

In previous versions of .NET sdk, we had implemented the following code:

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
protected HttpResponseException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    : base(info, context)
{
    ErrorId = (Guid)info.GetValue("ErrorId", typeof(Guid));
    StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)info.GetValue("StatusCode", typeof(HttpStatusCode));
    ShouldLog = info.GetBoolean("ShouldLog");
}
```

I have migrated to .NET 5 and we have started to face a lot of warning about it:

```
SecurityPermissionAttribute is deprecated: Code Access Security is not supported or honored by the runtime
```

What is the proper way to migrate it? Just remove the annotation or suppress the warning message?

Answer (score 2):

The Code Access Security (CAS) APIs are *non functional* in all of .NET Core upto .NET 5.
In other words: **they do... nothing**.

The types were carried over from .NET Framework 4 to allow easier migration of code, and nothing more - only to avoid compile errors. In some cases you may even get a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

You can leave it all in for now, but because it does nothing it serves only one purpose: to act as a reminder that (a) you should consider removing it, while (b) assessing the reasons why it was put in + what replacement safeguards you might want to add, to get something that resembles the protection that it gave you in .NET Framework.

More info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/code-access-security-apis-obsolete

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/code-access-security-apis-obsolete#cas-action):

> If you're asserting any security permission, remove the attribute or
> call that asserts the permission.
>
> If you're denying or restricting (via PermitOnly) any permission,
> contact your security advisor. Because CAS attributes are not honored
> by the .NET 5.0+ runtime, your application could have a security hole
> if it incorrectly relies on the CAS infrastructure to restrict access
> to these methods.
>
> If you're demanding any permission (except PrincipalPermission),
> remove the demand. All demands will succeed at run time.
>
> If you're demanding PrincipalPermission, consult the guidance for
> PrincipalPermissionAttribute is obsolete as error. That guidance
> applies for both PrincipalPermission and PrincipalPermissionAttribute.
>
> If you absolutely must disable these warnings (which is not
> recommended), you can suppress the SYSLIB0003 warning in code.

So, since you are using `SecurityAction.Demand`, you should remove it.